# How can my git repository be non-bare and have no working tree?

Tags: git, repository, git-checkout, git-bare

It seems like the central git repo I'm working with is both non-bare and has no working tree, which doesn't seem possible given my understanding of the definition of non-bare.

In the repository the result of `git rev-parse --is-bare-repository` is `false`

And when I look at its branch list the master branch is shown as checked-out with an asterisk.

However when I try to checkout a different branch I am met with:

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

I discovered this when I tried to push my changes from my local repo and got:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
```

Could someone help me understand the situation more? Ideally I would want the central repo to be bare and to be able to push there.

For context, I did not create the repo myself so I'm not sure if this is purposeful or happened by accident somehow.

Edit: For more info, here is the content of the config file

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
[receive]
        denyCurrentBranch = refuse
```

Comment: I'd double-check the URL first as everything *except* that `remote rejected` error makes sense: a bare repository has a `HEAD` but that `HEAD` is not actually checked out, by definition.

Comment: Do you mean the remote URL? I ran ' git remote -v' in my local repo and the URLs look as expected, though I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: I may have misread your question. There must be at least two repositories involved here, one on the server and one on your own system. In general, the server repository *should* be bare, i.e., have `core.bare` set to `true`, and there should generally be no `[receive]` section at all. Your own local repository should *not* be bare, i.e., should have `core.bare` set to `false`. Probably the URL (use `git remote -v` on your client-side local repository to check) is correct and these odd server settings are at fault.

Comment: It's not at all clear why your server side repository is set up this strange way.

Answer (score 0):

The bare value comes from the `.git/config` file. This is set to true automatically, when initializing a repository with `git init --bare`.

If that's not the case, the option can be set manually later:

```
git config core.bare true
```

Comment: Thank you that command may solve it, but I am mainly looking for an explanation of how/why my repo came to be in this state

Comment: Well, somebody might have created a "regular" Git repository and then only copied the `.git` folder to a server. Or created a regular Git repository on the server, noticed the mistake, deleted the working tree but left the `.git` repository untouched. I guess that question will remain unanswered